# Why is my text not wrapping in my table cell?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have created a parent table with two columns and within each column I have 6 child tables (3 in each) so I looks like a newsletter.

What I want is for the child table to extend down as I fill them with X amount of text but it's not working. I have set my child table widths and have set the CSS to `table-layout:fixed;` but when I type too much into one of the child tables the text flows out instead of wrapping.

It's strange because when I first created the tables it worked perfectly but now I can't figure out what I've done to stop it from working.

**And before people tell me to use divs, I'm using tables as it's going to be an email flyer for Outlook.**

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T53rD/1/)

HTML:

```
<table width="700" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">

  <tr>
    <td width="350" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top:10px;" scope="row">

      <center>

        <table width="90%" border="0" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="content">
          <tr>
            <td height="30px" align="left" bgcolor="#999999" scope="row" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Title</strong></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td  valign="top" bgcolor="#F4F4F4" scope="row" style="padding:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table> 

        </center>   
        <br /> 

    <center>
        <table class="content" width="90%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="30px" align="left" bgcolor="#999999" scope="row" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Title</strong></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" bgcolor="#F4F4F4" style="padding:10px;" scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>         
        </center>
        <br>

      <center>
        <table class="content" width="90%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="30" align="left" bgcolor="#999999" scope="row" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Title</strong></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#F4F4F4" scope="row" valign="top" style="padding:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>         
        </center>


    <td width="350" valign="top" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" style="padding-top:10px;">

      <center>
        <table class="content" width="90%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="30px" align="left" bgcolor="#999999" scope="row" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Title</strong></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td valign="top" bgcolor="#F4F4F4" style="padding:10px;" scope="row">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>         
        </center>
        <br>


      <center>
        <table class="content" width="90%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="30" align="left" bgcolor="#999999" scope="row" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Title</strong></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#F4F4F4" scope="row" valign="top" style="padding:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>         
        </center>
        <br />

      <center>
        <table class="content" width="90%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
          <tr>
            <td height="30" align="left" bgcolor="#999999" scope="row" style="padding-left:10px;"><strong>Title</strong></td>
            </tr>
          <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#F4F4F4" scope="row" valign="top" style="padding:10px;">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
          </table>         
      </center>

      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body {
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

table {
    table-layout:fixed;
}

strong {
    color:rgb(255,255,255);
    font-size:14px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for adding the fiddle, but it would help to have a fiddle that actually shows the problem. Even when I add long texts, they just seem to wrap perfectly fine.

Comment: @GolezTrol Sorry, I've added some text so you can see my problem

Comment: I've added an answer, although when you actually send this out, will you have words that long in your actual text? it happens because it's a continuous stream of characters, with no break.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding `word-break` to the `<td>` will fix this.

```
word-break:break-all;
```

**[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/T53rD/2/)**

Comment: Thanks Nick! I knew there was a simple answer to this :)

Answer (score 0):

Normal text will wrap just fine. Very long words will indeed not wrap, but I doubt if you would have words that long.

If so, you could consider adding `&shy;` in them to add soft hyphens. There are even libraries that can add those for you based on dictionaries, depending on any scripting languages you have access to.

In addition to that you might implement @NickRs suggestion to be safe, but remember that it will break the word in any place, so it might break in a place that is ugly or inconvenient. Not really what you would want in a newsletter.